# Facebook application tab instead of page

Tags: facebook, tabs

Do you know if there is any way to automatically open a tab/application from a page when user enters that Facebook Page?
The page has timeline activated but I didn't see any settings for this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, you can link users directly to your app, but users who navigate to the page itself can't be automatically redirected to an app